# Show that two statements are equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Would anyone be able to help with showing how the identity $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) = (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) - abc.$ I'm absolutely stuck on this question. Sorry that it's so basic $:P.$

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: When one these things, your last resouece is to multiply everything out and check if they are the same.

Comment: What's stopping you from just expanding the brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$
$$=(ab+ac+b^2+bc)(c+a)$$
$$=(abc+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2+a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+abc)$$
$$=(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-abc$$

What exactly were you stuck with?

Comment: Got stuck on converting part 3 to part 4.  :/

Comment: @Etched Then convert from part $4$ to part $3$.

Comment: Ahh of course, much clearer now, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let $a+b+c=S $. Then, $$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=(S-a)(S-b)(S-c) $$ $$ =S^3-S^2(a+b+c)+S(ab+bc+ca)-abc $$ $$ =S(ab+bc+ca)- abc $$ as required. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your $P$ on the last line is entirely unnecessary. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Rohan you should probably remove the abc = *P* seeing as you removed it from the equation ( and thanks a lot for the different approach to the question)